calling useQuery without passing a query function in React Query
I am trying to create a framework where 'widgets' are bound to data held in a React Query cache but are loosely coupled.
In an ideal world, I would like to tell my widget, use a dataset with a key of 'X' but not need to tell it anything about how to get hold of that data.
Another component deals with knowing that data needs to be sourced at a particular URL and it should be called 'X' but knows nothing about who the consumer of that data might be.
I had hoped to do this by calling useQuery with a queryKey of 'X' and nothing else (no query function). The idea is that it would either:
Use data from the cache if any existed
or
Sit in a 'pending' state waiting for there to be data otherwise.
When the data componenet refreshed the data with key 'X' then any listeners would update (because of the useQuery) and if no queries were listening then it would just populate the cache for the time when one did start to listen.
Unfortunatley the query function is a required parameter.
I have sort of got it to work by passing undefined as the parameter value but I also seem to need to pass 'enabled: false' to prevent it from trying to use the function and the enabled false is (I think) getting in the way of my calls to invalidateQueries() which I am calling to update the cache.
I know I have a really strange use case so I may just be trying to do something totally silly in the React Query world!

I think you have presented an XY problem (https://xyproblem.info/). If you have two components, how to they relate to each other? Are they siblings/children/completely unrelated?

(It is a dashboard like system) I guess siblings is probably the best term but they don't know anything about the others actual 'form'. They are both 'children' of a bit of configuration glue. The glue says to one component 'listen for data called 'X' and draw a chart of' it or 'listen for data called 'Y' and display it in a grid. Another widget might be told 'use this end-point and allow these parameters to be varied. When you receive data, broadcast it on a channel called 'X'. The UI bit doesn't know who will provide the data and the data bit doesn't know about the consumer(s).

I definitely am interested in more solutions but, for transparency, I have got a solution which is a reasonable work around.  Given that (in my XY world) all I want is to be able to call useQuery without knowing about the data function, rather than being able to call it with no param to mean 'leave the data function as it is' I have changed the code to look at the query in the cache, extract the current query function , and simply feed it back in. It is a little bit slower and more wordy but almost certainly imperceptible in execution time  given how many times it will be called.

"The UI bit doesn't know who will provide the data and the data bit doesn't know about the consumer." That's good, it resembles what is sometimes called Smart & Dump components. My general recommendation would be that the "smart" component handling data loading should be able to pass the data to the "dump" component via different means that the useQuery itself. Can there be context between them? In reality, QueryClient is the context, but if you use it that way, you can read queryClient.getQueryData directly instead of subscribing to useQuery, so maybe that context can be more direct.

Thanks Jakub. getQueryData definitly fits that side of the bill. However, nice feature of useQuery, is that, in addition to retrieving the data, it also handles the eventing side of the process and causes the re-render trigger. Interestingly (I think) the react Query docs mention using in a state management scenario (where this decoupled situation is potentially more common) I wonder if it might be a possible change to make @TkDodo? (As an aside, just to say, React Query package is really great!). For the moment, I have wrapped my above logic in a new hook (so can change in future easily)
